# show results of multiple mysql tables and sort

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have 4 tables:

```
Table 1: Users
    id
    username

Table 2: Acts
    act_id
    act
    user_id
    act_score
    act_date

Table 3: Votes
    vote_id
    act_id
    user_voter_id
    score_given
    date_voted

Table 4: Comments
    comment_id
    comment
    commenter_id
    act_commented
    date_commented
```

I want to show the contents of `Acts` `Votes` and `Comments`, based on User ID, combined in a list sorted in date order. Similar idea to Facebook's NewsFeed.

Sample output:

```
05-02-2014 10:00 Comment: "That's funny"
04-02-2014 12:30 Act Posted: "This is what I did"
04-02-2014 11:00 Comment: "Rubbish"
03-02-2014 21:00 Comment: "Looks green to me"
02-02-2014 09:00 Voted: +10 "Beat my personal best" by Cindy
01-02-2014 14:25 Act Posted: "Finally finished this darn website!"
```

I have tried to go down the create `VIEW` route to add all the required info to a table but
it was the wrong path. Now I'm not sure what to do!

Comment: Using a framework or simple php ? You could sort each line of your result in your php code before rendering it to the view with http://php.net/manual/fr/function.sort.php

Comment: Could you provide more details on your tables for example what is `score_given` the +10 displayed on your example? or it is the +10 along with the comment? or are all the comments held on the comment table and they are all referenced if so which field reference it?

Comment: @Prix Sorry it wasn't clear. On that row `+10` is the `score_given`, `"Beat my personal best"` is the `act` and `Cindy` is the user who posted the act

Comment: I see so each table is one of its own referenced by the user id, perhaps with `UNION` it might work out.

Comment: @Prix Yes, the user_id is the common field in all tables. I will read up on `UNION` in the manual. I'm getting sick of seeing that sql manual though! :)

Comment: Why would someone want to see in their feed acts that they did themselves?

Comment: @matt1985 if you could make a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with some sample data that did help a lot.

Comment: @eggyal It's not what they see themselves, it's the user who owns the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) to combine separate queries.  For example, to get the 10 most recent events across the three tables:

```sql
(
  -- my acts
  SELECT   a.act_date timestamp,
           'Act Posted' type,
           a.act description,
           u.username
  FROM     Acts a
      JOIN Users u ON u.id = a.user_id
  WHERE    a.user_id = ?
  ORDER BY a.act_date DESC
  LIMIT    10

) UNION ALL (

  -- votes on my acts
  SELECT   v.date_voted,
           CONCAT('Voted ', v.score_given),
           a.act,
           u.username
  FROM     Votes v
      JOIN Acts a USING (act_id)
      JOIN Users u ON u.id = v.user_voter_id
  WHERE    a.user_id = ?
  ORDER BY v.date_voted DESC
  LIMIT    10

) UNION ALL (

  -- comments on my acts
  SELECT   c.date_commented,
           'Comment',
           c.comment,
           u.username
  FROM     Comments c
      JOIN Acts a ON a.act_id = c.act_commented
      JOIN Users u ON u.id = c.commenter_id
  WHERE    a.user_id = ?
  ORDER BY c.date_commented DESC
  LIMIT    10
)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT    10
```

Comment: @eggyal the viewer is not included in any of the above queries, the users being referred to are all the page owner

Comment: @matt1985: I don't know what you mean by "*page owner*" since there is no such concept within your schema.  However it is worth noting that whilst acts/comments/votes are all directly related to a user (presumably that who posted the act/comment/vote), comments/votes are also related to acts: therefore in addition to the `user_id` of the related act, comments have `commenter_id` and votes have `user_voter_id`.  It is not clear by which of these users you wish to filter and which of the related usernames you wish to select.  My best guess is given above.

Comment: @eggyal sorry, the user for `user_id` `commenter_id` and `user_voter_id` are the same. So the user is called in the page (news.php?user_id=23) using `GET['user_id']`. This is info is used as all 3 of the above variables

Comment: @matt1985: It sounds as though your schema is badly denormalised.

Comment: @matt1985: If you're saying that `commenter_id` and `user_voter_id` will *always be the same* as the `user_id` of the acts to which they are related, then they violate [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) and can simply be dropped (one can always discover the relevant user from the `Acts` table).  However, I *suspect* that what you have said is not correct: after all, why would the only person able to comment or vote on an act be he who did the act?

Comment: @eggyal I thought you might be referring to a single call. It is true that `Acts` will contain acts posted by different users, `Votes` with different voters and `Comments` with different 'commenters'. On each call I want to display the acts, votes and comments all from the same user. Will your answer do that?

Comment: @matt1985: From the information given, it's very hard for me to understand exactly what it is that you're after.  However, the *approach* detailed above (combining separate queries with `UNION` and then sorting the result) can almost certainly be tweaked to achieve what you want: the exact queries to be combined does, however, depend upon your exact requirements.  Why don't you have a go at modifying it to suit your needs and come back if you have further problems?

Comment: I have used parts of your answer and also done some more reading up on `UNION`. I had the right schema, I maybe wasn't explaining properly. Any, thanks for your patience and help :)

Answer (score -1):

first of all make id as a foreign key and use it in rest of the 3 tables while inserting data into those 3 tables.

like for Acts table,table structure should be like below.

```
Table 2: Acts
    id  //this is user id which is stored in the session while login.
    act_id
    act
    user_id
    act_score
    act_date
```

The another thing to do is manage session for each and every user while he/she logged in.
Store user_id in the session for the further use like below.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id']=$_POST['ID'];
```

Then,fire select query for the particular table.I give you example of select query.

```
$sql="select * from Acts where id='".$_SESSION['id']."' ORDER BY act_date DESC";
$query=mysql_query($sql) or die("query failed");
```

Now, you will get result of Acts of particular user order by date.Then print it wherever you want.

Comment: Why in hell would you assign the `$_SESSION['user_id']` from the user INPUT `$_POST['ID']` FFS SQL injection all over. Properly retrieve it from the database and store the user id coming from the database, properly sanitize the data.